# What kind of glass is this?

Tags: cocktails

I would like to sell a pair of stemmed glasses, but do not know what to call them.  They are quite large (7.5" tall, and the bowl is 5.75" wide) and say "0.5 deru" on them, but have no other makers mark.  They seem too big to be called Margarita glasses or cocktail glasses, but I can't find any other suitable name for them. I am unable to post a picture of them. If anyone knows what they are called, I would sincerely appreciate it!

Thank you!!

Comment: You'll probably find them here http://www.derudesign.com/index.php?site=produkte&lang=engl

Comment: Thank you for the info!!  I didn't see them there, but you DID help me figure one important fact out -- I thought 'deru' was a unit of measurement or something - ha, not the name of the maker!!  Thank you!!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This(I guess you mean [these glasses](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Set-2-Large-Crystal-Margarita-Style-Stemmed-Glasses-Deru-Designs-/181185645856))  is a glass used to serve [Berliner Weisse](http://www.germanbeerinstitute.com/Berliner_Weisse.html) , in Berlin(where this drink comes from), we  simply call it "Berliner Weisse Glass".

Answer (score 0):

From your description, they sound like what I've heard called a 'fishbowl margarita glass'.

...  or it looks like just 'fishbowl glass' might be more correct.  Are either of these close?

http://www.webstaurantstore.com/libbey-3407-maximum-size-53-oz-super-schooner-fishbowl-glass/5513407.html

http://www.webstaurantstore.com/libbey-3408-maximum-size-60-oz-super-globe-fishbowl-glass/5513408.html